# Cordova build ios - says not a cordova project

Tags: cordova

I have a project originally created in Windows  - Angular.   We created the Cordova install/directory along side it.  It updates with the 'yarn run cordova' . - which correctly updates the ..\cordova\www directory.

Now, I have the directory mapped to my OS-X machine (host - Windows is running as a VM)

I pop into that directory and do a 'cordova platform add ios'

Not a cordova project is the error I get, so I do the command from Windows and it works fine.

I then run cordova build ios.
and get the error that it is not a cordova project.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova command looks for the `config.xml` file to determine if you're in a Cordova project. I run `cordova platform add ios` from the project root, where the config.xml is located. If you run cordova from directory like PROJECT/www/js, it looks for config.xml in a parent directory. Can you see config.xml on your Mac? If not you might need to map a higher level directory.